# ng-show condition (stored in a string form in variable ) is not evaluating angular js

Tags: angularjs, expression, ng-show, evaluate, ng-hide

I want to show a div according to a expression but the expression is stored in a variable in string form, is it possible to do evaluate an expression variable for `ng-show` / `ng-hide`.
like:

```
$scope.condition = {"SHOW":'(model1  === 'test1')'}
<div ng-show="condition['SHOW]"></div> something like this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's already answered by other post, Just wanted to add..
Since In your question you said.. *`the expression is stored in a variable in string form, is it possible to do evaluate an expression variable ..`*

The simple answer is NO you can't evaluate `angularjs` expression string variable , but you can only evaluate the valid expression.(either by JS or by angular variable)

**See this below code, to differentiate**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.condition = {
    SHOW1: "'test'  == 'NOTEST'",
    SHOW2: 'test' == 'test'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-show="condition.SHOW1">
    1.Not working, as it is simple string("'test' == 'NOTEST'").
  </div>

  <div ng-show="condition.SHOW2">
    2.Working, valid boolean Angular variable
  </div>

  <div ng-show="'test'=='test'">
    3.Working, valid boolean simple JS expression
  </div>
</div>
```

:

Comment: Upvoted your answer for you clarification around the string expression. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.test = 'test1';
$scope.condition = { show : ($scope.test  === 'test1')};
```

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-show="condition.show">something like this.</div>
```

which is the same as

```
<div ng-show="condition['show']">something like this.</div>
```

**TIP**

Instead of using `ng-show` / `ng-hide`, try to use `ng-if`. 
`ng-if` doesn't watch for changes on the binded variables inside this directive and can improve performance.

```
<div ng-if="condition['show']">something like this.</div>
```

Comment: Or in the view - `ng-show="condition['SHOW].model1 === 'test1'"`

Comment: @AlonEitan - exactly - but i'm PERSONALLY not a real big fan of additional 'logics' on view level. I try to keep logics on controller side - to keep clarity. It's personal I guess. :)

Comment: @daan.desmedt:  your solution is good, but I guess qstn was bit different, as it says  : *...but the expression is stored in a variable in string form..,*, :), It's like `show : "($scope.test  === 'test1')"`